# ubuntu server, php, ftp permissions

Tags: php, ubuntu, permissions, server, proftpd

Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 w/ LAMP and Webmin/proFTP (haven't really used webmin much; too much stuff flying around)

Issue:  With my user as owner of /var/www/ I can ftp files to the server, but PHP cannot handle files without www-data as the owner.

I also tried: 
`sudo adduser myUsername www-data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/`

This still did not allow my user to FTP upload to this directory; changing it back to `sudo chown -R myUsername:myUsername /var/www/` allows for FTP again.

**How can I setup permissions to able to use FTP and have PHP be able to handle files (cURL, fopen, exec, etc.)?**

Comment: A suggestion: you should strongly reconsider the pros and cons of allowing FTP access directly to www. Unless there is a specific technical reason for it, the negatives will almost always outweigh the positives in a production site. What will happen if you lose connection when an upload is only partially completed? What happens if your users access a larger file in the middle of an upload? In both cases your users will be served a broken file. You are better off uploading to another folder, then copying over to www.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the correct site to ask this question.

However try:

```
usermod -a -G www-data yourUserName
```

Answer (score 0):

The folder permission was set to 755, and it should have been 775 (write for group).

Comment: Always check those octals!

Comment: I know I feel so dumb, because I hit enter on chmod 775 command and immediately switched windows. Turns out I needed to enter my password for sudo again.... hasty work :(